# Do matrices that have det(A - *I) = 0 have any special name in math?

Tags: linear-algebra, terminology, definition

Since eigenvalues and eigenvectors are only possible for matrices that have `det(A - *I) = 0`, and as far as I can tell it makes them a very important special case, do those matrices (matrix `A` here) have any special name?

Comment: For any complex matrix, there will be some $\lambda$ such that $\det(A - \lambda I) = 0$, by the fundamental theorem of algebra. "Eigenvectors are possible" is a bit of a vague statement, but in some sense those might be the diagonalisable matrices - those are the ones which have a basis of eigenvectors.

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen By the fundamental theorem of algebra: For any real or complex $n\times n$ matrix there will $n$ complex values of $\lambda$ such that det$(A-\lambda I)=0\,.$ (Some $\lambda$ may have multiplicity greater than one.)